# как работают некоторые поля кода

Tags: c++

```
void print2DUtil(Node* root, int links = 0, int bits = 0)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    print2DUtil(root->right, links, bits + 1);


    int flag = links ^ links << 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < bits; i++)
    {
        if (flag & 1 << i)
            cout << "  |";
        else
            cout << "   ";
    }
    if (bits == 0)
        cout << "--";
    else if (links & 1 << bits - 1)
        cout << "   `--";
    else
        cout << "   .--";


    cout << root->Name << "," << root->sex << "," << root->generation;
    cout << endl;


    print2DUtil(root->left, links | (1 << bits), bits + 1);
}
```

как работают

```
int flag = links ^ links << 1;
else if (links & 1 << bits - 1);
print2DUtil(root->left, links | (1 << bits), bits + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такое -

```
links & 1 << bits - 1
```

это число, которое не нулевое, если бит с номером `bits-1` (считая с 0 для младшего бита) в `links` установлен. Просто 1 сдвигается влево на нужное количество полей, и операция `&` зануляет все биты, кроме того, в котором во втором значении единица.

```
links | (1 << bits)
```

С точностью до наоборот - в `links` устанавливает бит с номером `bits` равным 1. Остальные не трогаем.

```
links ^ links << 1
```

Тут выполняется побитовое исключающее или числа и сдвинутого влево числа. Но зачем именно - что получается в результате, не могу сказать. Наверняка есть какая-то простая формула, но мне она не встречалась.